# What is currently the standard for database case

Tags: database, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

So have I read tons of convention about database and programming. However, I don't remember if there is one suggesting a standard case for database.

**Is it standard for a database to be case sensitive or is it standard to be case insensitive?**

I know some database technology default case vary from one to another (SQL, Oracle, mysql, etc.) This isn't what I'm looking for, because the default case for some technology may be again the standard.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about case in the SQL statements or about `VARCHAR`/`TEXT` fields?

Comment: About case sensitivity for the data, what ever the column type.

Comment: ok, in that case the answer provided by @a_horse_with_no_name is what you're looking for: it always depends on the collation that has been configured for the column in question.

Comment: According to his answer, a standard collation to use should be case insensitive. Since it is the standard since 1986. Right? I don''t have any particular requirement for the case, I just one to use a standard one.

Comment: No, that part relates to unquoted identifiers. For data, the DBA is responsible for setting up the schema with the correct collation required for the data in question.

Comment: @AXMIM: no that's not true. The SQL standard says nothing about case sensitivity when comparing **data** - and I don't think it specifies any "standard collation"

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, this is the actual answer I was looking for, because my concern was about data. Sorry it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL standard requires **un**quoted identifiers to be case **in**sensitive. This has been in the SQL standard since the beginning (so back in 1986 or so)

*Quoted* identifiers however are case **sensitive**

So according to the standard `foo` and `FOO` are identical, but `"foo"` and `"FOO"` are not.

If you are talking about comparison of character values, then the SQL standard makes this dependent on the collation the character strings are defined in: "*The comparison of two character string expressions depends on the collation used for the comparison*"

The standard lists some collation names, but does not mention whether they are supposed to be case-sensitive. In fact the documentation of the "collation descriptor" only lists:

> - The name of the collation.
> - The name of the character repertoire to which it is applicable.
> - A list of the names of the character sets to which the collation can be applied.
> - Whether the collation has the NO PAD or the PAD SPACE characteristic.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the [SQL 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2008) and [SQL 1999](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:1999) define database to be case insensitive. But there are certain database that compliant with the standards and there are certain which have exceptions. So it depends on which database you are using. You have to follow the rules defined by the database which you are using.

So lets say you are using Oracle then it for sure that it is fully compliant with the standards. But lets say you are using MySql then its dependent on the file system like below query on windows works

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (ID INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE "Test" (ID INTEGER); -- Gives Errors , table already exists
```

But on linux it works

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (ID INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE "Test" (ID INTEGER); -- Creates the table Test
```

Comment: The part with "but on Linux it works" is only true for MyISAM, not for InnoDB (and least not when using one container file instead one file per table )

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:- Indeed, but I was trying to make a point that it  varies with different database.